# Task.Run sometimes returns twice

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, azure-functions, slack

I have an azure function app that I call from a slack slash command.
Sometimes the function takes a little while to return the data requested, so I made that function return a "Calculating..." message to slack immediately, and run the actual processing on a Task.Run (the request contains a webhook that I post back to when I finally get the data) :

```
Task.Run(() => opsData.GenerateQuoteCheckMessage(incomingData, context.FunctionAppDirectory, log));
```

This works mostly fine, except every now and then when people are calling the function from slack, it will return the data twice. So it will show one "Calculating..." message and then 2 results returned from the above function.

BTW, Azure functions start with : 
public static async Task

Thanks!

UPDATE : here is the code for the function:

```
    [FunctionName("QuoteCheck")]
     public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
     {
          var opsHelper = new OpsHelper();

          string bodyContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          var parsedBody = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(bodyContent);
          var commandName = parsedBody["command"];
          var incomingBrandId = parsedBody["text"];
          int.TryParse(incomingBrandId, out var brandId);
          var responseUrl = parsedBody["response_url"];

          var incomingData = new IncomingSlackRequestModel
          {
               UserName = parsedBody["user_name"],
               ChannelName = parsedBody["channel_name"],
               CommandName = commandName,
               ResponseUri = new Uri(responseUrl),
               BrandId = brandId
          };

          var opsData = OpsDataFactory.GetOpsData(context.FunctionAppDirectory, environment);

          Task.Run(() => opsData.GenerateQuoteCheckMessage(incomingData, context.FunctionAppDirectory, log));

          // Generate a "Calculating" response message based on the correct parameters being passed
          var calculatingMessage = opsHelper.GenerateCalculatingMessage(incomingData);

          // Return calculating message
          return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, calculatingMessage, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
      }
 }
```

And then the GenerateQuoteCheckMessage calculates some data and eventually posts back to slack (Using Rest Sharp) :

```
    var client = new RestClient(responseUri);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outgoingMessage), ParameterType.RequestBody);

    client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: That's impossible! Can you show the code for the Azure function?

Comment: Updated with the code above!

Comment: What were you expecting to achieve with this? `Task.Run(() => opsData.GenerateQuoteCheckMessage(incomingData, context.FunctionAppDirectory, log));`

Comment: What do you mean by **posts back**?

Comment: I want the function to run through to the end, return the calculating message as an immediate response, and that Task.Run to go off and do its thing, and eventually return another response with more detail. It can take up to 10 seconds to get the full data set.

Comment: And by posts back, I mean responds to the webhook URL that slack sends with a fuller data set.

Comment: @evolmonster I would rather have your Azure Function post a message in a ServiceBus and have it return your message and have another Azure Function being triggered by the ServiceBus that would then do the actual computation...

Comment: That is a good idea. I already have a function that reads from a queue I set up for a similar thing. That would for sure be a good solution.

I guess I am hoping to get a better understanding as to why this task might be returning twice. Or perhaps if that isnt possible, that it may be my code that posts the response...

Answer (score 1):

Using Kzrystof's suggestion, I added a service bus call in the function that posts to a queue, and added another function that reads off that queue and processes the request, responding to the webhook that slack gives me :

```
public void DeferProcessingToServiceBus(IncomingSlackRequestModel incomingSlackRequestModel)
{
    var serializedModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(incomingSlackRequestModel);
    var sbConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING");
    var sbQueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("OpsNotificationsQueueName");
    var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(sbConnectionString, sbQueueName);
    var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(serializedModel);
    client.Send(brokeredMessage);
}
```